# Can you please explain the tree in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, tree

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def add_child(self,child):
        **child.parent=self**  ---- PLease explain this line. I am not getting it. 
        self.children.append(child)


def build_product_tree():
    root = TreeNode('Electronics')
    laptop= TreeNode('Laptop')
    root.add_child(laptop)
    return root
```

When we are adding the child , we are giving  **child.parent=self** I am not understanding this. Please cna anyone explain this ?

Comment: When `child.parent=self` is executed, `self` is a reference to `root` because the code does `root.add_child(laptop)`. This passes the object `root` into `add_child()`  as `self`. That is what the `.` means.

Answer (score 0):

This class supports get parent node directly by child node, and get child nodes by parent node.

The parameter `child` of function `add_child` should also be of type `TreeNode`.

The line you feel confused simply set the input child node's parent node to self, which means in Python "this class".

If you've learnt linked list. You could understand it as: `next_elem->prev_node = this;`

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_child(self,child):
        child.parent=self
        self.children.append(child)
```

`add_child(self, child)` is a method to add a child node to an existing TreeNode.

`child.parent = self` - This will add the current node - (*to which we are adding the child node*) as a parent node of `child`.

Say there's an existing node `A`.

```
A.parent = None
A.children = []
A.data = 7
```

There is a node B that looks like this:

```
B.data = 5
B.parent = None
B.children = []
```

Now we want to add node B as child to A. So we call `A.add_child(B)`

If B is a child of A then **A should be made the parent of B.** (*because your TreeNode has a reference to parent*) That is what this line does.

`child.parent=self` - This will be - `B.parent = A`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have code that includes a `parent` reference in every node. In theory this is not necessary, as it adds redundant information, but it sometimes makes algorithms easier, at the cost of the extra memory used for it.

It is redundant because if a node has a child in its `children` list, then obviously it is the parent of that child. It would be inconsistent if that child node would have a parent reference that was referencing some other, unrelated node (or `None`). So your code must do some work to make sure that such back-references (from child to parent) are consistent with the "downward" references (from parent to child, via `children`).

That is what this line is for. Whenever a child node is added to a parent's `children` list (which happens in the line below the one you ask about), we *must* ensure consistency, and set the child's `parent` back-reference to *that* parent, which in this case is `self`.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `TreeNode` has the following attributes, `data`, `children` and `parent`. A newly created instance has the `parent` attribute set to `None`.
Since the root node does not have a parent, only children (if any).
We are calling the method `add_child` on the *instance* of `TreeNode`, thus `root` is the parent and any child element of `root` will have it as the parent. Hence we are setting the `parent` attribute of the child node to `self` which is the instance of parent node.